# Is it good to set SqliteConnection static variable?

Tags: sqlite, unit-testing, static

I am developing a mobile app using Xamarin Form and using sqlite-net-pcl to access sqlite db.
I think that mobile app is used by one user at one time, there is not much concurrent database access scenario. So now I only use one DbContext instance, I mean I instantiate the dbcontext and get sqliteConnection at the start up of App. Then pass it to any class that need it.

But I am wondering is it good idea to set a static sqliteConnection variable, so It is very convenient to use it wherever I need. I know the static variable is not good for unit test. But do I need unit test db access function ? I mean I am using sqlite-net-pcl to access, I don't think I need test its db access functions.

thanks in advance!